# Is it convenient to go from Latvia to Russia?

Tags: visas, germany, russia, latvia, lithuania

I am in Germany. I want to go in this way: Dresden-Warsaw-Lithuania-Latvia-Moscow-Beijing.

I have to bypass Belarus because I do not want to apply for the visa.

The problem is, is it convenient to go from Latvia to Moscow now? I mean the border crossing.

I travel by bus or train. Actually I have no interest in Lithuania or Latvia at all. I just want to go to Moscow as soon as possible.

Comment: I have been through that way driving and had no problems at all (but have a passport, which changes the experience somewhat).  But I don't know what 'convenient' means. Do you mean the border controls at the Latvian frontier?  Or 'convenient' in the sense of if there are civilized coffee shops and amenities enroute? Or 'convenient' in the sense of quicker than some other route?  What mode of travel?  I need to place a close vote on your question with the hopes that you will clarify what you're after.